# global link in views is displaying %3f etc

Tags: views, navigation

I have made a global text variable inside a view which I set as a link. This link contained parameters of the other fields found in the view. This is the link I set it for:

```
subscription_status?staff_action=reject&first_name=[field_first_name_value]&last_name=[field_last_name_value]&email=[field_email_address_value]&teamid=[field_team_nid]&nid=[nid]
```

This worked fine. Now, all of sudden it stopped working. Now the end part of the url reads:

```
  subscription_status%3Fstaff_action%3Dreject%26first_name%3D%0A%20%20Jo%26last_name%3D%0A%20%20E%26email%3D%0A%20%20myemailaddress%40gmail.com%26teamid%3D%0A%20%20Varsity%20Girls%26nid%3D381&staff_action=reject&first_name=_%20%20Jo&last_name=_%20%20E&email=_%20%20myemailaddress&teamid=_%20%20Varsity%20Girls&nid=381
```

it repeats everything and adds in a lot of replacers ie: %3f. Why is this all of a sudden happening and how can I stop it?